# Position Node missing

Tags: node-editor, geometry-nodes

The *Position* node is missing. I don't know how to fix this. I googled, but what I found does not relate to my current problem.

[image: Position Node missing]

Comment: Search for texture coordinate

Comment: Related: [Can't find the node! Which node is available in which Blender version?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/273541)

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

The [Position](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/geometry_nodes/input/position.html) geometry node is only available in 3.0+ versions of the Geometry Nodes editor, not the Shader Editor.

You can either use a [Texture Coordinate](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html) node to get the local position of geometry or use the Position output of a [Geometry](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/geometry.html) node to get the world position.